# How to access an instance variable from a do block?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

The following code does not work. It says `undefined method 'table_name' for nil:NilClass`

```
@members = Members.all

table member_list_rows do      
  if @members.table_name == members
    row(0).background_color = '3498db'
  end
end
```

Full code

```
class MemberPdf < Prawn::Document
  def initialize(members, view, allcount)
    super(top_margin: 50)
    if members.size != allcount
      @warn = " (Not all members)"
    else
      @all = " All"
    end
    text "Showing#{@all} #{members.size} Members", size: 18, style: :bold, align: :center, color: "636363"
    text "#{@warn}", size: 11, align: :center, color: "858585"
    @members = members
    @view = view
    member_list
  end

  def member_list
    move_down 20
    table member_list_rows do
      self.row(0).align = :center
      if @members.table_name == "members"
        row(0).background_color = '3498db'
      else

      end

      row(0).text_color = "FFFFFF"
      self.row_colors = ["DDDDDD", "FFFFFF"]
      self.header = true
      #self.cell.text_color = "B3B3B3"
      row(0).columns(0).style size: 20
    end
  end

  def member_list_rows
    [["Name", "Awardunit", "Address", "Contact", "Level of Entry", "Current Award", "Disabled?"  ]] +
    @members.map do |member|
      [member.name, member.awardunit.name, member.address, member.name, member.entrylvl, member.currentaward, @view.yesno(member.disabled)]
    end
  end
end
```

Members controller

```
    if params[:commit] == "Clear"
        params[:q] = nil
    end

    respond_to do |format|
        format.html
        format.pdf do
            pdf = MemberPdf.new(Member.search(params[:q]).result.order( 'name ASC' ), view_context, Member.all.size)
            send_data pdf.render, filename: "Members_List.pdf", type: "application/pdf", disposition: "inline"
        end
    end
```

Comment: Maybe you can `puts` the initial text to the console instead of using `text` in your PDF-file, that might allow you to see how many members you have. However, I still fail to see where `table_name` should be defined. `@members` will just hold an `Array` which will not answer to your `table_name` even if it is not `nil`. Maybe you can add another `puts @members.count` inside `member_list_rows` to help with debugging?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is due to `@members` is nil.You are doing it wrong.

Change this

```
@members = Members.all #Wrong
```

to

```
@members = Member.all #Right
```

Always remember,the Model name should be **singular**.

Those are called **Naming Conventions**. For more information,read these Style guides([Ruby](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide) and [Rails](https://github.com/bbatsov/rails-style-guide))

Comment: Sorry, its a mistake in the question. In the actual code its correct

Comment: Can you Post the full code where that Snippet belongs to?

Comment: Where do you have this line @members = Member.all? In your members_controller?

Comment: Yes. Then it pass members to this class. This piece of code use that data to render a list of member. The member data is coming to this class and im sure of it because the list gets rendered.

Comment: @EApubs Ok Can you please post your members_controller also?

Comment: Added the parts you need :-)

Comment: Oh sorry I had to cancel this project and didn't try it. Your answer is right! Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

Most likely `table` method is changing context, in which you don't have access to the `@members` instance variable anymore. This can be achieved easily by this sample code:

```
def do_stuff(&block)
  cls = Class.new
  cls.instance_eval(&block)
end

@test_var = "test_var"

do_stuff { puts @test_var }
```

You will receive nothing, because `@test_var` does not exist in the `cls`.

Comment: Reading the [Prawn source code](https://github.com/prawnpdf/prawn/blob/master/lib/prawn/table.rb#L129-L143) it seems you are quite right.

Answer (score 0):

Am not sure what you are doing with "table member_list_rows". Didn't get that.
In the third line though, it should be

```
if @members.table_name == "members"
```